# Is there an alternative to `SELECT INTO` within an `IF EXISTS (...)`?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

So I'm trying to write an integrity check.

`Foo`s have `Top`s and either an `Alpha` xor a `Beta`.

`Top`, `Alpha` and `Beta` all reference `Gamma` and whichever `Alpha` or `Beta` a `Foo` has must reference the same `Gamma` as its `Top`.

i.e.

```
foo1 --> top1 --> gamma1
foo1 --> alpha1 --> gamma1
```

is allowed,

```
foo1 --> top1 --> gamma1
foo1 --> alpha1 --> gamma2
```

is forbidden

I've been trying

```sql
DO $check$
DECLARE
   violation_type TEXT;
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(
       SELECT CASE WHEN alpha.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'alpha' ELSE 'beta' END INTO violation_type
       FROM
           Foo o
           LEFT JOIN top t ON o.top_id = t.id
           LEFT JOIN alpha a ON o.alpha_id = a.id
           LEFT JOIN beta b ON o.beta_id = b.id
       WHERE
           t.gamma_id <> coalesce(a.gamma_id, b.gamma_id)
   )THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Foo Violation: There are %-type foos whose top references a different gamma', violation_type;
   END IF;
END $check$;
```

But that fails because

> ERROR: SELECT ... INTO is not allowed here

Which is a shame because I'd very much prefer not having to duplicate this code, just to check once for `Alpha` and once for `Beta`.

Is there an alternative that can be used, here, or am I stuck with two checks?

Comment: . . Sample data is more helpful than abstractions.

Comment: Store `gamma` in foo and use composite foreign key relationships.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No composite foreign keys. We just spent weeks untangling a database model s.t. we could get rid of this one.

Comment: You don't need a `Select INTO` :: `EXISTS(...)` yields a boolean, which can be the condition inside an `IF()` (if an if is allowed) or `WHERE(...)` (when not)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `SELECT INTO` in an `EXISTS` subquery. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

> The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion.

Instead, use `SELECT INTO` and check with `IF FOUND ...` in the next step:

```
DO
$check$
DECLARE
   violation_type TEXT;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO violation_type
   CASE   WHEN f.alpha.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'alpha' ELSE 'beta' END
   FROM   foo        f
   JOIN   top        t ON t.id = f.top_id
   LEFT   JOIN alpha a ON a.id = f.alpha_id
   LEFT   JOIN beta  b ON b.id = f.beta_id
   WHERE  t.gamma_id <> coalesce(a.gamma_id, b.gamma_id);

   -- IF violation_type IS NOT NULL THEN  -- alternative
   IF FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Foo Violation: There are %-type foos whose top references a different gamma', violation_type;
   END IF;
END
$check$;
```

Alternatively, you could check whether the variable has been assigned like shown with a comment.